# Unknown encoder 'libvorbis'

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am facing problem in converting videos by using ffmpeg. Its installed and all the libraries are also there. but using certain commands its showing for different encoders that they are Unknown.

Unknown libvorbis

Unknown libvpx

Unknown libogg
etc

Can anyone help please.

```
/bin$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 0.10.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 30 2014 15:49:19 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with PHP. In a command line interface run the command `ffmpeg`, then paste the **complete** console output in your question.

Comment: i put the complete console in question

Answer (score 0):

Your `ffmpeg` build has `--enable-libvorbis` for Vorbis audio encoding support, but lacks `--enable-libvpx` so you have no VP8/VP9 encoding support.

0.10.15 is old. Users are recommended to use a build from current git master, or, if that is not possible, a recent release.

You have a few options to resolve this issue:

- Compile `ffmpeg` using whatever configure options that will fit your needs. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile Guide for CentOS, RHEL, Fedora](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).
- Or download a [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). The static build contains support for Vorbis and VP* encoding.

Then point your scripts to your new build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please can you tell me how to point my script to new build or should i uninstall old one?

Comment: @Aisha You probably don't need to uninstall the old one if you don't want to. You should make a new question (search for an existing one first) involving how to make the script use a particular binary because it's a different issue than this question. Make sure to include your actual code.